# what is the equivalent of "data-hover:" in a ruby on rails' link_to block

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following html

```
<a href="#" data-hover="Seraglio"><span>Seraglio</span></a>
```

How do I convert it to RoR ?

Comment: You need to tell what you mean by RoR.  Do you mean `erb` or `haml` or any other templating language(you might be using).  I believe that code you've posted is already valid RoR view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```

So for your example, in **.erb format**:

```
<%= link_to("#", {"data-hover" => "Seraglio"}) do %>
  <span>Seraglio</span>
<% end %>
```

Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: worked. thanks for the documentation as well! I'll be reading it.

Comment: No Problem.  There are a bunch of ways that you can do this, several you can find in the docs.  Happy Reading :D

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way:-

link_to(body, url, :data =>{:hover => your_data_hover_value})