# Ruby on rails links, navigation

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with Ruby on rails link effects.
My current code is:

```
<header class="navbar navbarfixed navbar-default navstyle>
<%= link_to "Cocktails",root_path, class:"btn btn-lg", id: "logo" %>
<nav class="cl-effect-5 container">
<a href="#"><span data-hover="new">new</span></a>
<a href="#"><span data-hover="test">test</span></a>
<a href="#"><span data-hover="test">test</span></a>
</nav>
</header>
```

So i need to convert the current html link style to ruby, so the effect is still there(cl-effect-5). I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779979/what-is-the-equivalent-of-data-hover-in-a-ruby-on-rails-link-to-block), but i get syntax error for some reason, even though i double checked everything...

Comment: Your syntax looks okay to me. Can you post the error and backtrace?

Comment: You forgot double quote for class on this line : `<header class="navbar navbarfixed navbar-default navstyle>`

Answer (score 0):

One difference I noted with your code and the linked solution is that you have the hovers in the `<span>` versus in the `<a>` tag.

```
= link_to '#', data: { hover: 'test' } do 
  'Test'
```

I think that's what you may be looking for (not that the `span` is wrong per se). Also, make sure your application.css and application.js manifests are including bootstrap (or whatever front end UI kit you're using)!

Comment: I fixed the effect not working, by adding an id to this link. But now the effect works, but the hover text doesn't show up. I am using: http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/, effect number 5.

Comment: Did you verify that your front-end framework that handles hover effects loaded (i.e, bootstrap or whatnot)?

Comment: The effect works but, the hover text won't show up... 
Html code is then: <a data-hover="new" href="/"><span>new</span></a>

Comment: What is your front-end framework (Bootstrap, Foundation, your own, etc.)?